# Expectation and children

Tags: probability

What is the expected number of children if the probability of having a child(boy or girl) = 1/2 and if you want a boy and a girl?

E(No of children) = ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whatever sex the first-born kid is, our waiting time **after that** until a child of the opposite sex is born is $\frac{1}{1/2}=2$. So the expected number of children is $3$.

For more detail, we can assume without loss of generality that the first-born is a boy. Let $y$ be the expected additional number of children  until a girl is born.

The second child is a girl with probability $\frac{1}{2}$. In that case the additional number of children  was $1$. And with probability $\frac{1}{2}$, the second child is a boy, in which case the expected number of additional children is $1+y$. Thus
$$y=\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{2}(1+y).$$
Solve for $y$. We get $y=2$, so the expected total number of children is $1+2$.

Or else we can do the problem the hard way. Let $X$ be the total number of children. Then $X=2$ with probability $\frac{1}{2}$, $3$ with probability $\frac{1}{2^2}$, $4$ with probability $\frac{1}{2^3}$, and so on. Thus
$$E(X)=2\cdot\frac{1}{2}+3\cdot\frac{1}{2^2}+4\cdot\frac{1}{2^3}+\cdots.$$
We leave it at that. The infinite sum turns out to be $3$, but a summation of series argument for that is quite a bit longer than the first way we solved the problem. 
Solve for $y$. We get $y=2$.

Comment: Hmm why are not counting the first. I mean if the first kid is a boy and then the next kid a girl the expected value is 2. isn't ?

Comment: Andre - what if it's boy first, and boys for the next N kids? I just saw your edit now. At first I thought you meant 'e' as in 2.71828....  I'd avoid 'e' as a variable, although I see you have 155K so I'll shut up now.

Comment: @gopal: Yes it is. I find it more convenient to look at expected number of **additional** children, children after the first. Then we add $1$ to that at the end. One reason I do it that way is that the number of additional children has a well-known distribution, the *geometric* distribution.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer: One should accept suggestions from taxpayers. The $e$ is now a $y$.

Comment: Great The first one is easy method. Thanks for the help.

Comment: +1 - a complex answer with a simple result, i.e. 3. (and thanks for dealing with my simple minded confusion)

Answer (score 0):

We need at least one child. When we know the gender of this child, we keep having children until we get one of the opposite gender. There is a $1/2$ chance the first extra kid is the one we need, a $1/4$ chance it's the second, and so on.

Hence we need $1+1/2+2/4+3/8+4/16+\cdots=3$ children.